# React Thunk Resolver reasie error: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'

Tags: redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Got this error:

> A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.

In this line

```
> [getAuthnUser.fulfilled](state, { payload }) {
```

Component:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { AuthnRes } from '../tikexModule/Types'
import axios from 'axios'

const initialState: any = {
    resp: null,
}

const namespace = 'user'

export const getAuthnUser = createAsyncThunk(
    `${namespace}/getAuthnUser`,
    async () => {
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'me',
            headers: { crossDomain: true },
        })
        return data
    }
)

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'authnUser',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [getAuthnUser.fulfilled](state, { payload }) {
            state.resp = payload
        },
    },
})

export default userSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't recommend the object notation for `extraReducers` anymore, especially with TypeScript you should be using the ["builder notation"](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation).

As you see, the object notation is not playing well with TypeScript.

```js
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(getAuthnUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload })=> {
            state.resp = payload
        }),
    },
```